# Dividing rails results into logical pairs

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model that can belong(s)_to 6 values of a related model. In my view, I want to display 2 of the values in one column, two in another column and two in the last column.

What's the best/easiest way to group these records for easy display. What I thought of so far:

- Using group_by, but I cannot find any decent documentation on that
- doing some kind of loop and store the results in a temporary array
- Just do find.all and handle the logic in the view
- Query the results from the relationship 3 times, once for each pair

What is your best practice?

Comment: I don't understand how your models are related. In RoR, models don't usually belong_to values, but to other models. Please elaborate. Minimal code fragments would help.

Comment: Considering "cannot find any decent documentation" - did you read the Rails guides? The one on the query interface is quite good IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

1) In your model create 3 methods: column_1, column_2, and column_3 like:

```
def column_1
  "#{association_1.field} #{association_2.field}"
end
```

2) In your query add includes on your belongs_to associations to make it run faster.

3) Call the methods in your view.

On the other hand, displaying complex things via model methods such as links and such, might be a bit ugly, and you might have to write those methods in a helper instead of your model.